# not able to install driver for DCP - 1510

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printing, printer

I was unable to install the driver that came along with the brother's DCP-1510 monochrome multipurpose printer, so I contacted the printer supplier, who told me to open my device manager, right-click on my DCP-1510 icon and go to update device driver and navigate to the cd-rom drive where the driver package cd-rom was loaded, I did what he said and magistically, the print-function worked; Here is the visual summary of what I mentioned upto now:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I purchased the printer as it was a multipurpose printer, and I can make xerox copies out of it, So I'm sure there's no hardware defect, but It should had also been able to scan the documents into my PC, but **Here's where the problem is:**
[image]

My PC doesn't detect a scanner, and I can't scan the files from "Windows Fax and Scanf", I tried scanning externally, trying to connect the pc from the printer(DCP-1510), but it doesn't connect. So, I think it might be that the driver did not install how it supposed to had. How can I get the scanner to work?

When I try reinstalling the driver or installing the driver from the package, the following error occurs:
[[image: opening flash player file[10]]
[image]
[image]
[image]
And believe me, I restarted the computer countless number of times, without any applications in the background but the installer, and tried it again and again, until I finally resolved here.

Comment: There are a number of things that could potentially be the problem.  The first step would be to start with the basics.  USB printers are finicky as far as the installation sequence.  Disconnect the printer from the computer and uninstall the printer.  With the printer disconnected, reinstall the driver.  At a point in the process, the installation wizard will tell you to connect the printer, so do it at that point.  If it doesn't work, report back and we can try a bigger hammer.

Comment: Try running Setup on the DVD. That should install both printer and scanner drivers. Browse to it in Windows explorer and double-click it.

Comment: @fixer1234, I tried reinstalling again and again but it doesn't work. Please take a look at the edits I have made above, and could you tell me what the bigger hammer might be?

Comment: @hdhondt, I tried it from the cd as well.

Comment: Did you actually run the SETUP.EXE (or similar) that's on the CD?

Comment: @hdhont, Like I posted above, There's the flashplayer's start icon, which leads to install the MFL-pro suite button, when I click the process begins ..... and terminates afterwards, I would've expected a single installer on the cd, but there isn't.

Comment: @bzal, just to confirm, you uninstalled the printer driver and the printer was not connected via USB when you ran the installation wizard?

Comment: @fixer1234, yes, but I also did it when it was connected. But the installation site does say, that we must ensure that the printer remains disconnected before installation: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp1510_eu_as&os=93&dlid=dlf005346_000&flang=4&type3=11&dlang=true            The notes before downloading say so

Comment: If this is a new printer, I would get Brother involved.  Most of the things I can think of that it could be are things they would be in the best position to diagnose and fix (bad firmware in the printer, bad driver, etc.).  It might require warranty printer replacement.  Are you using the USB cable that came with the printer (an extremely long budget cable could cause problems)?

Comment: Yes, I am using a cable, but it's not extremely long

Comment: @fixer1234, Are there any other softwares that I could use just to access the scanner?

Comment: It's because most of the other features work, just the scanner part does not get connected to my PC

Comment: Phew!!! found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for future DCP-1510 series users, if this problem arises then, first refer to the screenshots above and complete the partial step as in the given sequence. I thought this would be the complete installation but no, it was partial.

So now refer to the second screenshot in the question above, under other devices, there in the third list, you can see an unknown device(should had been named scanner or something), then follow the steps, the same done for the printer. After you do this, you should see a scanner item under imaging devices in the device manager and that's it! However, the utilities are not available, but you can use the windows fax and scan, to scan documents as well as something like picasa or adobe photoshop to directly import images from your scanner.